# Adding a style or class to a button on hover, programatically using Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

Let's say I have this loop of buttons

```
    <button
  *ngFor="let item of items"
  [ngStyle]="{'color': fontColor}"
  (click)="selectedItem = item"
  class="dropdown-item">
  <span class="font-weight-bold text-center">
    {{ item.quantity }}
  </span>
  {{ item.measurementUnit }}
</button>
```

I want to set a different color on hover, but I can't do it via css pseudo selectors because I am getting the color as an input from another component.

I have seen some solutions where they declare a variable `onHover` and then they set it to `true` or `false` on `(mouseenter)` and `(mouseleave)` events.

But I cannot do this since it's a `*ngFor` loop and it will be reflected on every button in the loop. Any solutions to this? Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want to do this for one particular button, i would suggest to use index number for styling or attaching the mouseenter event to it

Comment: You could include the color property in the `items` objects.

Comment: Do you know the index of the button in the loop you want to apply (mouseenter) or is it random order but you know the button has a unique ID / reference?

Comment: You should be able to call a function and pass in the `$event` to get the `target`. Then use `Renderer2` to change the `target` css style